# Jenkins Git configuration issue - Credentials drop down not found

Tags: git, jenkins

In my Jenkins I can't find the credentials drop down.
My Jenkins version is 1.609.1 and I'm configuring it in openshift cloud space.
Following is a screen shot.

[image: Ui screen in jenkins]

Comment: Have you tried looking under 'Advanced'?

Comment: Yes.
It has Name of repository (blank to create default) and Refspec (blank to create default) fields only.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using? I feel like, with some versions of Jenkins, one had to let it look at the repo first before it would prompt for authentication (e.g. enter the URL information for the repository, then tap 'Apply' or 'Save', and it will bring you to an auth view).

Comment: My version is 1.609.1. Couldn't find any prompt like that.

Comment: @jwir3 : The 'credential' info will appear even without 'advanced'.  Problem could be in specific versions (as you have already asked)

Comment: Please add more info about your installation(platform, versions, etc).  Please provide info asked by @mainframer as edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Git Plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), the *credentials* plugin is a dependency of the *Git* plugin. It should be automatically installed while you install Git plugin from:

> Manage Jenkins --> Manage Plugins --> Available --> Git plugin

If you installed the *Git* plugin manually by putting the `.hpi` or `.jpi` file into the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` folder directly, there's a possibility that you could miss the dependent plugins like the *credentials* plugin.

Comment: Thanks mainframer. Upgraded plugins restarted Jenkins and it did the trick.